# Как оформить дополнительное пояснение?

Tags: пунктуация

Это будет одна из крупнейших теплоэлектростанций страны, одна из первых в Индии со сверхкритичными параметрами пара  — 540 °С  при давлении около 260 атмосфер.

540 °С - это числительное, следовательно, как приложение его рассматривать нельзя, тогда по какому принципу здесь ставится тире? Не лучше ли использовать скобки? Или здесь вообще не нужно тире, потому что это специальная литература?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Это будет одна из крупнейших теплоэлектростанций страны, одна из первых в Индии со сверхкритичными (540 °С при давлении около 260 атмосфер) параметрами пара.*

*Это будет одна из крупнейших теплоэлектростанций страны, одна из первых в Индии со сверхкритичными - 540 °С при давлении около 260 атмосфер - параметрами пара.*

Comment: Спасибо большое. А вариант с тире по какому правилу? Пояснение?

Comment: Это вставная конструкция со значением пояснения, уточнения.

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли про слово-температура. И тогда можно без тире.
Безличное упоминание цифр тире не заменит.

Это будет одна из крупнейших теплоэлектростанций страны, одна из первых в Индии со сверхкритичными параметрами пара, температурой 540 °С при давлении около 260 атмосфер.

И у Вас надо что-то делать со словом одна, оно два раза в одном предложении.